# Reading data from, and writing data to S3 in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have run same application twice ,once with community edition ( only 6GB memory us-west) and once with one driver and one worker( 60 GB Memory , eu-central) surprisingly app in community edition run much faster in terms of reading and writing the data into S3 .

I haven't found any explanation to this poor result as our clusters are much more powerful than community edition , I have even try one driver, one worker ( up to 60 ) again it will take a lot more than community edition. We are using S3 , as a datasource in our application, we read a 9 million rows .csv file , make some analysis on it and again write the result on S3, as we have mounted our buckets to bdfs .

```
 df=sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(delimiter=',',header='true',inferschema='true').load("dbfs:/mnt/mount1/2016/rrdb_succesful_sales/*")
```

the code i use to write to s3:

```
top_profit_product.coalesce(1).write.csv("dbfs:/mnt/mount2/tappalytics/profitability_report/weekly/top_profit_product",mode='overwrite',header=True)
```

I dont' think there would be any problem with my code , is it? any advice?

Comment: what is the size of the result file? how much time does it take in both options? where is S3 files locate? US or EU?

Comment: @Yaron S3 that i read from is located in Singapore,S3 that i write to is located in Frankfurt, community edition is in us-west, and my driver, worker is in Frankfurt. The cvs file i want to read had about 9 million rows and it would take maybe 15 to 20 minutes to be read with my real cluster and around 6 to 8 minutes with community edition

Comment: if you are working with data in different locations then you get to take the bandwidth overhead of long-haul links, delays in setting up HTTPS connections and pay the bills for the reads. Avoid.

Answer (score 1):

This the databricks filesystem here, not the OSS Apache S3 clients or the Amazon EMR driver, so you'll have to take it up with them.

For the ASF code, the s3a client delays come in from: number of HTTP requests; bandwidth to s3, seek times on HDD. HTTPS request setup/teardown is vey expensive; the latest s3a clients do a lot less seeking, though you have to choose the right option for your datasource.

If you are working with an s3 bucket on a site different from where your VMs are, that'll be your bottleneck. You will be bandwidth limited, billed per MB, and better off skipping 500K of data rather than seeking to a new location by aborting the active HTTP GET and setting up a new TCP stream.

tip: s3a://landsat-pds/scene_list.gz  makes for a good 20MB test source; hosted on US-east, AWS pay for your downloads. Spark 2 also adds its own CSV reader.

Comment: Yes You are right, as i am using starter package support services are limited with data bricks

Comment: what if get rid of 'inferschema=true' in read and  coalesce(1) in write, do you think it will accelerate ?

Comment: inferschema triggers a full scan through the data to get the schema. Get rid of that immediately.